# Elimination of the knight: Direct or Indirect?

Tags: analysis

[image]

Between 18. Na2 and 18. Rac1, which is more favorable for white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Na2 is the best though it takes the Knight away from the Centre of the board hindering basic Chess Principles but if you take a note then Black is ok on Centre and K-side and his weakness resides in the Queenside .

So Na2 removes the Knight from b4 and the Bishop can dominate on light Squares like c6 where it can attack the d5 Square . Also the a6 Pawn will become weak once the Knight is lost .

Comment: That's one powerful knight, huh?

Answer (score 1):

IM Silman gives this position as problem 3 in *The reassess your chess workbook*. He recommends 18. Na2:

> Short played the surprising and strong **18. Na2!!**. This idea ... shows that White considers the b4-Knight to be more important than its brother on e4. The reason is simple: the b4-Knight is the main guardian of Black's weak points on a6, c6 and d5.

IM Silman does not consider 18. Rac1 in his analysis.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer the question. 18.Rac1!! also gets rid of the knight.

Comment: (Hence the title of this post)

Comment: @JossieCalderon 18.Rac1 gets rid of the knight on b4 how exactly? Note that Black is in no way forced to reply to 18.Rac1 with 18...c5.

Comment: @Scounged that's correct. White then plays 19. Nd2.

Comment: @JossieCalderon I see how that takes care of the knight on e4, but not the one on b4.